# Using jQuery with elements in hidden div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Don't know if this is posible..

I have an ASP.Net page that has a hidden div on it. When the user performs some certain  function the div becomes visible (`display='block'`). This is happening in the VB.Net code behind for many reasons.

```
dvDetail.Style("display") = "block"
```

I need to have some jQuery assign a plugin to a TextBox that is in the hidden div but I am having a problem doing that - I am a bit new to jQuery. It seems that the TextBox does not exist on the page after it is loaded because of the `display='none'` of the div at that time and by the time the user performs the action that causes the div to display it is too late for the `$(document).ready` because it has already run. I have tested the functionality in a non-hidden part of the page and the jQuery works just fine.

To respond to many of your fine answers - the foloowing test code is as close as I got to what I actually need - it actually works but it causes the hidden div to become visable when the page first loads which is not what I need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=dvDetail]').show(function () {
        $('[id$=btnDelete]').click(function () {
            alert('Delete clicked');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: As long as the element is rendered on the page jQuery should be able to pick that element when appropriate selector is specified. Can you post the HTML rendered on the page and how you are seleting it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with asp.net, but if the element (div) is loaded in the DOM, jQuery should be able to find it, wether it's hidden or not. Have you checked if the element does indeed load in the DOM. You could check that (and debug the javascript) with Chrome's developer tools, or FF's firebug.

Comment: The div is not being loaded in the dom at pageload as far as I can tell because of the display='none' attribute on the div. It gets loaded later by the line of code in my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your jquery code outside the $(document).ready function but make sure it exist after the textbox html.

Comment: I'm not a jQuery expert - have used it a little for about a year. Does that go against the way jQuery was designed to be used? Just asking as everything I have ever read about jQuery states that it is designed to be inside the $(document).ready function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the ASP.NET control property `.Visible = False` and the CSS attribute `display: none` - if the control is set to `.Visible = False`, the control is never rendered on the client side, and as a result any client-side scripts will not be able to find it.

Check as jcane86 said to make sure the control is actually rendered on the client side - it may not be displaying, but it should be in the actual HTML output of the page.  If it's there, jQuery should be able to find it (and if you debug Javascript w/ your browser tools of choice, you can test with `$("#MyClientSideId").show()` in your JavaScript console, as Hunter said).

Comment: The div is defined in the HTML code as display='none' The div style is set to dvDetail.Style("display") = "block" in the code behind at a later time by user action. The visable property is never used.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the hidden elements like this:

`$("div:hidden").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});`

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a name selector instead of an element selector? I have tried $('[id$=dvDetail]:hidden').each(function () but seems to not be working. The issue with the type selector is that I have 3 hidden divs in the page.

Comment: As far as I know, ASP.NET attaches ID to the divs in a certain format. Can you get that format and then apply the filter to select on those with the matching pattern?

Comment: The name selector is working. I have used both $('[id$=dvDetail]') and $('#<%=dvDetail.clientID %>') and they both resolve the client ASP.Net mangled name ok. On my page it resolves to $('#MainContent_dvDetail')

Comment: Also just tried using the acutal resolved name $('#MainContent_dvDetail:hidden') which did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following html:

```
<div style="" id="hide">
  <textarea ></textarea>
</div>
```

I'm able to manipulate the hidden textarea with jquery then show it at the end of the chaining.

```
 $("#hide").children('textarea')
.text('hello there')
.css({width: '300px', height: '300px', padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #ccc'})
.parent().show();
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

PS: If the element is being loaded at a later time after the document ready has finished for example, you will need to bind an event for the code above to work, using the .bind() method or my favorite .delegate()

Comment: Yes - this will work great and I may end up having to move all the hiding and displaying of the divs client side. Right now it is beneficial for me to display this hidden div from server side code so I am trying to resolve the issue within that scenario - the bind() and delegete() look interesting. I am not familiar with them and will check that out - thanks.